# Emacs Warning (initialization) -- File error

Tags: emacs

Whenever I open emacs on a linux server I'm using I get the following message which takes up half my screen:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/[my username]/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, sm

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

What's happening here? I don't have any issues editing, except for this warning message in the way. How can I address this?

EDIT:
My `~/.emacs` file contains the following:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; Supermongo (SM) mode stuff
;;
(require 'sm)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append
       '( ("\\.sm\\'" . sm-mode) )
       auto-mode-alist)
      )
```

Comment: By fixing the error in your initialization file. We can't see it from here.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll see what's in there.

Comment: @KenWhite: that's not the problem: `'sm` is equivalent to `(quote sm)` in lisp and that's the (usual) form that `require` requires (ha!) The problem is that the OP either does not have the Supermongo package or his `load-path` is set incorrectly and emacs cannot find it. OTOH the setting of the auto-mode alist *does* look suspicious, but if it is a problem, it's a secondary one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `load-path` variable is probably set missing something. You need to add a path so that the `sm.el` (or `sm.elc`) file can be found by emacs. Something like this at the beginning of your `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/directory/containing/sm.el")
```